# Unable to scrape Website in java using htmlunit

Tags: java, web-scraping, htmlunit

Im new to Scrapping , i am trying to scrape a website using Htmlunit. i have logged in the site but after going across 2nd page , i am logging off from the website. 
https://hotelservice.hrs.com/portal/?lang=en

the code

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.AjaxController;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebRequest;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPasswordInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine;


public class HrsHtmlUnit {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HrsHtmlUnit unitTest = null;
    try {
        unitTest = new HrsHtmlUnit();
        unitTest.homePage("601296", "xcvgxcvxcv", "xvxcvxc");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void homePage(String uName, String pwd, String cate) {
    try {



        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);

        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://hotelservice.hrs.com/portal/?lang=en");


        final String pageAsXml = page.asXml();


        HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("loginForm");


        HtmlTextInput hotelNumber = form.getInputByName("loginForm:hotelKey");
        HtmlPasswordInput password = form.getInputByName("loginForm:password");
        HtmlTextInput userName = form.getInputByName("loginForm:username");


        HtmlSubmitInput submit = form.getInputByName("loginForm:submitButton");


        hotelNumber.setValueAttribute(uName);
        password.setValueAttribute(pwd);
        userName.setValueAttribute(cate);

        HtmlPage adminPage = submit.click();

        HtmlAnchor anc = adminPage.getHtmlElementById("allApplications:division:1:application:0:hsv");



        HtmlPage click = anc.click();
        System.out.println("Title :: " + click.getTitleText());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I have loggedinn the site , but in the loggedinn page when i click **Hotel Self Administration Tool (HSA)** link. i am going to loginpage again.

please help.!!